# How to prevent hadoop stream from closing?

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop

I built a basic web parser that uses hadoop to hand of urls to multiple threads. This works pretty well until I reach the end of my input file, Hadoop declares itself done while there are still threads running.  This results in the error  org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed.  Is there anyway to keep the stream open long enough for the threads to finish up?  (I can with reasonable accuracy predict the maximum amount of time the thread will spend on a single url).

Heres how I execute the threads

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text word = new Text();
        private URLPile pile = new URLPile();
        private MSLiteThread[] Threads = new MSLiteThread[16];
        private boolean once = true;

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) {

            String url = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer urls = new StringTokenizer(url);
            Config.LoggerProvider = LoggerProvider.DISABLED;
             System.out.println("In Mapper");
            if (once) {
                for (MSLiteThread thread : Threads) {
                    System.out.println("created thread");
                    thread = new MSLiteThread(pile);
                    thread.start();
                }
                once = false;
            }

            while (urls.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    word.set(urls.nextToken());
                    String currenturl = word.toString();
                    pile.addUrl(currenturl, output);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

            }

        }
```

The threads themselves get the urls like this

```
    public void run(){
            try {
            sleep(3000);
                while(!done()){
                    try {
                    System.out.println("in thread");
                      MSLiteURL tempURL = pile.getNextURL();
                      String currenturl = tempURL.getURL();
                      urlParser.parse(currenturl);
                      urlText.set("");
                      titleText.set(currenturl+urlParser.export());
                      System.out.println(urlText.toString()+titleText.toString());
                      tempURL.getOutput().collect(urlText, titleText);
                      pile.doneParsing();
                     sleep(30);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                          pile.doneParsing();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread done");

        }
```

And the relevant methods in urlpile are

```
public synchronized void addUrl(String url,OutputCollector<Text, Text> output) throws InterruptedException {
        while(queue.size()>16){
            System.out.println("queue full");
            wait();
        }
        finishedParcing--;
        queue.add(new MSLiteURL(output,url));
        notifyAll();
    }

    private Queue<MSLiteURL> queue = new LinkedList<MSLiteURL>();
    private int sent = 0;
    private int finishedParcing = 0;
    public synchronized MSLiteURL getNextURL() throws InterruptedException {

        notifyAll();
        sent++;
        //System.out.println(queue.peek());
        return queue.remove();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can infer from the comments below, you can probably do this in each of the map() function to make things easy. 
I saw you do the following, to pre-create some idle threads.
You can move the following code to

```
if (once) {
  for (MSLiteThread thread : Threads) {
     System.out.println("created thread");
     thread = new MSLiteThread(pile);
     thread.start();
  }
once = false;
}
```

to,

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    public void configure(JobConf job) {
       for (MSLiteThread thread : Threads) {
         System.out.println("created thread");
         thread = new MSLiteThread(pile);
         thread.start();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
       OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) {
    }

}
```

So, that this could get initialized once and for that matter, don't need the *'once'* condition check anymore.

Moreover, you don't need to do make idle threads as above.
I don't know  how much performance gain you'll get creating 16 idle threads as such.

Anyways, here is a solution (may not be perfect though)

You can use something like a countdownlatch [Read more here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/countdownlatch-example-in-java.html#ixzz2ZnaE6HVM) to process your urls in batches of N or more and block off until they are done. This is because, if you release each incoming url record to a thread, the next url will be fetched immediately and chances are that when you are processing the last url the same way, the map() function will return even if you have threads remaining in the queue to process. You'll inevitably get the exception you mentioned.

Here in an example of how probably you can block off using a countdownlatch.

```
 public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
                Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

            @Override
            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) {

                String url = value.toString();
                StringTokenizer urls = new StringTokenizer(url);
                Config.LoggerProvider = LoggerProvider.DISABLED;

            //setting countdownlatch to urls.countTokens() to block off that many threads.
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(urls.countTokens());
            while (urls.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    word.set(urls.nextToken());
                    String currenturl = word.toString();
                    //create thread and fire for current URL here
                    thread = new URLProcessingThread(currentURL, latch);
                    thread.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

            }

          latch.await();//wait for 16 threads to complete execution
          //sleep here for sometime if you wish

        }

    }
```

Finally, in URLProcessingThread as soon as a URL is processed decrease the latch counter,

```
public class URLProcessingThread implments Runnable {
    CountDownLatch latch;
    URL url;
    public  URLProcessingThread(URL url,  CountDownLatch latch){
       this.latch = latch;
       this.url = url;
    }
    void run() {
         //process url here
         //after everything finishes decrement the latch
         latch.countDown();//reduce count of CountDownLatch by 1

    }
}
```

**Probably problems seen with your code:**
At `pile.addUrl(currenturl, output);`, when you add a new url, in the meantime all the 16 threads will get the update (I'm not very sure), because the same **pile** object is passed to the 16 threads. There is a chance that your urls get re-processed or you can probably get some other side effects (I'm not very sure about that).

**Other suggestion:**

Additionally you may want to increase map task timeout using

> mapred.task.timeout

(default=600000ms) = 10mins

> **Description:** The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates
>   its status string.

You can add/override this property in mapred-site.xml

Comment: That declares the task a failure if it actually does time out which isn't exactly what I want but it seems to be on the right track.

Comment: Ahhh! I might have missed some of the details in the question. Are you saying you have threads running from a single map task and when the map finishes processing the input it has, Hadoop quits?

Comment: More or less.  The threads a while to process each input which is why I have more then one of them.  However once hadoop declares the map task as finished the threads have no where to place their output.

Comment: Can you show how are you executing the threads inside a map() function? I can probably answer you better that way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  Hopefully this will solve the issues I've been having.